# Currency Formatter for different Locale in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I want to convert this String: `1000000` to following format: `10,00,000` but, I am getting output like this : `1,000,000` which is wrong. I need `10,00,000`.

**My Code :**

```
NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
         inputnumber = newString;
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setCurrencySymbol:@""];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[formatter setCurrencyGroupingSeparator:@","];
// [formatter setCurrencyDecimalSeparator:@"."];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[inputnumber doubleValue]];
inputnumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:num];
```

Comment: Will the input string always be 7 digits long?

Comment: You'll need to write your own formatter for this

Comment: I'm curious why you need the commas like that?

Comment: @wain in India they have words for 100,000 (lakh)  so 10,00,000 is 10 lakh. So the formatting makes sense in that locale.

Comment: @Wain: It's an Indian Currency Format.So, OP has to set `@"en_IN"` as `currencyFormatter Locale`. Check my Answer.

Comment: It's likely that this format will also need something like 10,00,000,000 to denote 10 crores, another step in he same numbering system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an Indian Currency Format. So, you have to set `@"en_IN"` as `currencyFormatter Locale`.

**Working Code :**

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currencyFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@""];
[currencyFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_IN"] autorelease]];
NSLog(@"Final Value :: %@", [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1000000]]);
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Swift check this:**

```
 let initalValue:NSString = "1000000"
    let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    currencyFormatter.locale = NSLocale (localeIdentifier: "en_IN")
    let formattedValue = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(initalValue.doubleValue)
    print(formattedValue)
```