# how to display number values with comma separation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

The number Value is 120000.

1. List item
      This number Value I need to display 1,20,000.

Comment: Are you sure you want "1,20,000" and not "1,200,000"?

Comment: @ThomasW In india currency there is only 2 digits in second coma

Comment: yes i want "1,20,000"this format only..This for indian rupees

Comment: possible duplicate [Formatter for Indian Currency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463298/formatter-for-indian-currency)

Answer (score 6):

You can use NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle for desired result.

```
NSNumberFormatter *indCurrencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[indCurrencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[indCurrencyFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_IN"]];
NSString *formattedString =  [indCurrencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:120000]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**Example:**

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // Here you can choose the style

NSString *formatted = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: 120000]];
```

or you can use:
 `[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator]`

**Update:**

In Indian currency format you have to set `@"en_IN"` as numberFormatter `Locale`, just add this line :

```
  [numberFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_IN"]];
```

Comment: i got NSlog like this 120,000 but i want this format 1,20,000

Comment: add this line [numberFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_IN"]];

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDecimalNumber *price = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"120000"];
NSLocale *priceLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-in"]; 

NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currencyFormatter setLocale:priceLocale];
NSString *format = [currencyFormatter positiveFormat];
[currencyFormatter setPositiveFormat:format];

NSString *currencyString1 = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:price];
DLog(@"%@",currencyString1);
```

Comment: It is working  what i want..thanks u so much..

Comment: @palavesakumar: you can accept the answer or upvote as well !