# Int NSFormatter for swift 123456 to 1,23,456

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting this value 123456 and I want to convert this value to 1,23,456 in swift programming. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an indian style number format, where 100,000
(written as 1,00,000) is one ["lakh"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh).

Translating and simplifying  the Objective-C code from [Currency Formatter for different Locale in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463298/currency-formatter-for-different-locale-in-ios) gives:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_IN") // English (India) locale

let number = 12345678
let string = formatter.stringFromNumber(number)!
println(string) // 1,23,45,678
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_IN") // English (India) locale

let number = 12345678
let string = formatter.string(for: number)!
print(string) // 1,23,45,678
```

Comment: I have written everything except locale. Thanks Martin :-)

Comment: ok kool. Its done :-)

Comment: I have another approach for this. You can set groupingSize and secondaryGroupingSize to get the correct format.