# Why is that an invalid number?

Tags: swift, swift3

There are very different ways of displaying numbers, for example:

```
16666,67
16666.67
16.666,67
16.666.67
```

Those are all valid numbers for different regions and / or countries.
In our usecase we have to use following representation:

```
16.666.67
```

Because

1. Its easier to see how big the number is using the thousands seperator
2. We needed to prevent wrong user inputs so we are replacing all commas with a period

Though, for a numberformatter with a period as decimal sperator `16.666.67` is not a valid number:

```
self.numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
self.numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal;
self.numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0;
self.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
self.numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = ".";

print(self.numberFormatter.number(from: "16.666.67");
```

which is resulting in `nil`. Why is that an invalid number? And how can I solve that problem?'

**EDIT**

Following test:

```
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal;
    numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0;
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
    numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = ".";
    numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = ".";

    print(numberFormatter.number(from: "16666"));
    print(numberFormatter.number(from: "16666,67"));
    print(numberFormatter.number(from: "16666.67"));
    print(numberFormatter.number(from: "16.666"));
    print(numberFormatter.number(from: "16.666,67"));
    print(numberFormatter.number(from: "16.666.67"));
```

output is:

```
Optional(16666)
nil
Optional(16666.67)
Optional(16666)
nil
nil
```

Comment: I haven't used NumberFormatter yet, but could it be because your Sting isn't a number? Shouldn't it be "16666.67"? Let the formatter do it's thing?

Comment: Yes. But that is exactly the point. Your example would work fine for the numberformatter. But we need to display a thounds seperator in the `TextViews` and we are taking this text and tranform it into a number.

Comment: How do you expect a processor to do your interpreting for you? It's a formatter for numbers, and the String you're supplying it, well, isn't. You mean the function you're calling should be smart enough to remove periods *before* formatting?

Comment: Im actually asking for a solution in general. I do not expect to use only the numberformatter to solve this.

Comment: See my answer. Yes, it involves some *intelligent* coding *before* call NumberForamtting, still....

Comment: Replacing both decimal and thousands separators by a period seems like a bad idea to me. How should "123.456" be interpreted then?

Comment: funny thing is that swift numberformatter has no problem converting "123.456" to a valid number as you can see in the example which i posted above.

Comment: The reason being that "123.456" is a String that *can* be automatically be converted into a number "dumbly" (that is, without making an assumption for you but not others).

Comment: @Mulgard: NSNumberFormatter has a locale property, and by default uses the current user's locale. So depending on your regional settings, `.` is interpreted as a thousands or decimal separator.

Comment: I know that. But setting `groupingSeperator` and `decimalSeperator` should do the trick in my opinion. Otherwise I cant see the use of those parameters.

Comment: But how to you expect the number formatter to know how it should convert `"16.666"`? In your output it becomes `16666`, but with your settings it could have been `16.666` that were the correct number. You shouldn't use the same symbol for grouping and decimal separator.

Comment: Because there are 3 characters after the `.` and not two? sounds simple for me.

Comment: @Mulgard, why do you think that there cannot be 3 digits after decimal point?

Comment: @Mulgard Are 3 decimal-numbers an incorrect number? ;-) You can't make the assumption that 3 numbers make the grouping separator the correct choice.

Comment: because i set `numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;`? again simple. but I see your point ofcourse. Having fractionDigits set to 3 would cause a problem.

Comment: As far as I know, the number formatter *ignores* minimum/maximumFractionDigits when parsing a string. I think you have to implement your own logic. And note that even "1,16,666.67" can be a valid number ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29742750/1187415)) – so you cannot rely on groups always having 3 digits.

Comment: Why don't you simply create your own functions? string to_double_dot(const double) and double from_double_dot(const string)?

Comment: @Aziuth the answers pointed out that this will be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the **String** *16.667.67* is no less an invalid number as *This.is.a.number.00*.

You need to make your String variable be something valid.

EDIT:

Based on the comments this sounds like a language behavior issue (Java versus Swift).

I'm seeing other comments on handling this, but to me, it looks like it gets down to how the Swift NumberFormatter automatically handles a String input with multiple decimal points. Unlike (some) other languages, you may need to do some *pre-formatting* of the string before calling NumberFormatter.

Comment: and that is exactly the point. how? for example it would be possible to replace the decimal seperator with a comma. but how?

Comment: I simply want an API that is doing those things for me.... I mean in java i would not have any problems at all since java simply does not care about the format, it is able to convert all examples which I posted above to a valid number. But even something like "replaceLastOccuranceOfString" isnt existing in Swift.

Comment: Your best bet is to implement a parser that will convert the input to a correctly formatted `Float` for the `NumberFormatter`.  Then you can set the style to locale such that it will display your currency format.